# How to dynamically resolve artifact release version as parameter defaultValue in Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to create a Jenkins multibranch pipeline with a parameter which defaults to next build release version resolved from pom.xml in a maven project. What I have tried is to store release version in an environment variable and interpolate into defaultValue attribute of the parameter, however in the Jenkins GUI I only get "Null" in the input field. If i echo BUILD_RELEASE_VERSION inside a stage, the release version is correctly displayed.

[image]

What I have tried

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
      BUILD_RELEASE_VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion().replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")
  }

  parameters {
      string(
              name: "RELEASE_VERSION",
              description: "Release version.",
              defaultValue: "${env.BUILD_RELEASE_VERSION}")  
  }
  .....
}
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly default to next release version is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like below example

```
def version
node {
       // Icheckout the repo
       checkout scm
       version = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
       
      /*
        //or read value from pom file, if you have youe own buildIn method
        version = readMavenPom().getVersion().replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")
       */
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any;
    parameters {
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: version, description: 'Current POM version')
    }
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                echo "Params : ${params}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after the first run you can see the pom file version number on the VERSION parameter field

[image]